# jQuery addClass to a tag problem

Tags: jquery, element, anchor, addclass

I have this in my html code:

```
<ul id="navlist"
<li id="tabItem1"><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
<li id="tabItem2"><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
<li id="tabItem3"><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
<li id="tabItem4"><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class to the a element with jquery like this: (its not working)

```
var currentTab = 1;

$(document).ready(function()
{        
  $("li#tabItem" + currentTab + ":has(a)").addClass("navlistHover");
  //console.log("li#tabItem" + currentTab + ":has(a)");
});
```

When a delete the a element and do it like the next example, than there is no problem.

```
$("li#tabItem" + currentTab).addClass("navlistHover");
```

---

I've tried the following code:

```
$('navlist li#tabItem' + currentTab + ' a').addClass('navlistHover');
```

but it's not working, very strange

Comment: Anyway you could store in `currentTab` active tab element `var currentTab = $("li#tabItem1");` It'd be nicer. Then you would add classes like this `currentTab.children("a").addClass("navlistHover");`

Comment: Did you try adding quotes around the 'a' element in the has() statement like $("li#tabItem" + currentTab + ":has('a')").addClass("navlistHover");

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('navlist li#tabItem' + currentTab + ' a').addClass('navlistHover');
```

The `:has()` selector selects items that have the `a` element as children:

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/has

Comment: That'll add the navListHover to the anchor tag, not to the LI which is what he is looking to do.

Comment: That's not how I interpreted the question.

Comment: He does say: 'I want to add a class to the a element'

Answer (score 0):

It's working if you add the html closing tag for

`<ul id="navlist">`